# How to include files in Symbian Deployment so it will be accessible?

Tags: qt, symbian

I tried to include files in my Qt program (for symbian) and ran it via the emulator. No files were exported. The code I've been using in my QMake file is:

```
symbian {
    TARGET.UID3 = 0xe22a34fe
    # TARGET.CAPABILITY += 
    TARGET.EPOCSTACKSIZE = 0x14000
    TARGET.EPOCHEAPSIZE = 0x020000 0x800000

    addFiles.sources = 01.jpg 02.jpg 03.jpg
    addFiles.path = .
    DEPLOYMENT += addFiles
}

OTHER_FILES += \
    03.jpg \
    02.jpg \
    01.jpg
```

As such, a call to QDir::entryInfoList() will reveal no files:

```
QDir dir = QDir::current();
dir.setFilter(QDir::Files | QDir::Hidden | QDir::NoSymLinks);
QFileInfoList list = dir.entryInfoList();
// list is empty.
```

Am I missing something in the .pro file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you deploy these files, where are you expecting them to be placed?

```
addFiles.path = .
```

to me is indeterminate - the is no 'current' directory when the files are deployed.

Provide a path you know exists. I've certainly used the app private directory for this purpose:

```
addFiles.path = \private\e22a34fe
```

...then you can get the directory of your files with

```
QApplication::applicationDirPath()
```

If you are running on the emulator, also check if the files are deployed. If you are using the 'real' Symbian emulator (rather than the rather horrible QT version), you'll find the file system under epoc32\winscw

Comment: I would've guessed its being placed in the same dir as the binary. That's what the "." suggests, right? You mentioned `\private\e22a34fe` .. is it always this directory? You also mentioned the real Symbian emulator, which I'm going to look for now. Really wonder why it's so complicated to ship assets with Qt. I mean - how else would you develop certain things if this is so complicated. :-(

Comment: If you can get away with using simulator shipped with Qt SDK, i.e. if you don't use any custom wrappers over native Symbian functionality, don't try using standard Symbian emulator (a.k.a. epoc) - it's slow and it doesn't emulate real device well. Develop on desktop using simulator and then test on real device.

Comment: The \private\xxxx directory is the Symbian app data directory, where xxxx is the UID of your application (minus the '0x' of course).

Comment: Thanks or both replies. No device available at this time. What hits me is that `\private\xxxxx` is not a real path on OSX (my operating system) and the application is launched with `applicationDirPath()` being somewhere in `/Users/sebastian/Library/`. Hilarious IDE this is.

Comment: +1 for distinguishing 'horribe QT' simulator and 'real simulator' (that is, epoc32). I'd give you another +1 for 'horrible' if it were possible:) Qt's simulator has little to do with Symbian system, while epoc32 mimics it very well to finest details. I still remember how it was trying to search for E: memory card on my computer hahahaha.

Answer (score 2):

On Symbian OS all exe and dll files are kept in /sys/bin directory, and each application keep it's data in /private/APPUID directory (where APPUID is the application UID3). Deploying files to "." will deploy the files to application's private directory (in your case it will be /private/e22a34fe as KevinD mentioned, because you have "TARGET.UID3 = 0xe22a34fe" in your .pro file).

To find out where the files will be deployed on device check the appname_template.pkg generated by qmake. It's syntax is pretty straightforward (and in case of any problems you can [read the documentation](http://library.forum.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-35228542-8C95-4849-A73F-2B4F082F0C44/sdk/doc_source/ToolsAndUtilities94/Installing-ref/PKG_format/index.html)).

I'm not sure which directory is returned by QDir::current() on Symbian, but the documentation states that QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() should return path to application's private dir.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use those files only withing your application then you can try using Qt Resource file.

To add a new Resource file File->New File->Files and Classes->Qt->Qt Resource file. Then add the necessary files u need. All the images will be converted into equivalent unicode text or something. 
[Deploying files with Qt application](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/How_to_Deploy_and_Use_Files_in_Application_Private_Directory_for_Symbian)

Comment: This is a good thing to know for newbies, as the Qt resources are very easy to use, but please for the sake's of your nerves remember: Qt resources are **read-only**, while deploying files vis .PKG rules allows read-write to them.